# eclipse transfer failed zip file is empty

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I'm trying to add a JSF library to my project. 
But when I try to download from eclipse, it says 
"Transfer failed. Zip file is empty". The screenshot below shows what I'm talking about
[image: Transfer failed. Zip file is empty]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Adding Mojarra Manually When Eclipse Luna/NEON/Oxygen JSF Download Library Is Empty...**

When I was setting up a fresh install of JavaEE on my laptop today, the JSF Download Library would not return any results to download. Some searching suggested that I had to change my proxy settings but since I was not behind a proxy,

Actually some peoples are saying  Oracle [Oracle Java web App](http://java.net) temporarily / Website is offline / Shutdown that's why its not downloadable ...

[image: If this problem is happening try out this]

it would not help me. Lucky enough, JSF are just another bunch of jars that can be added to a user library.

You can download the JSF Scroll down here for newest versions of JSF jars...

Download JSF API JAR  [JSF API jar file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/)

Download JSF IMPL JAR  [JSF IMPl jar file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/)

Then simply;  click the **“Manage Libraries”** icon on the JSF capabilities page  **click “New”** and *name your library*

**click** “Add external jars” and browse to the jars you downloaded

[image: Name your libraries that you can take back your jars files]

[image: When jars are added then use your jsf as it is...]

Finally you are fully featured to the JSF Mojjara Library

Thanks...

Comment: I have add the two jar files but no change.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has shutdown the java.net site that Eclipse is trying to get the JSF files from.

Eclipse has an open bug report [516918](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516918) about this issue but as yet there is no fix.

Comment: Thank you! I move to spring now.

Comment: @zuolizhu: What a weird 'change'... ?

Answer (score 0):

Download [Eclipse Link](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/) 2.X.Y (Version 3.x.y seems to have different libs)

From the Download use the libraries / jars

- eclipselink/jlib/eclipselink.jar
- eclipselink/jlib/jpa/jakarta.persistence_X.Y.Z.jar

And place them into your user Library by either

- The "Manage Libraries ..." Button on the very right of your screenshot 
  or
- Eclipse -> Windows -> Preference -> Java -> Build Path -> UserLibraries