# getting empty zip file error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I'm following [this tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jsf/jsf-crud-application-example/#javaClassCreation) and getting this zip file error you can [watch here.](https://youtu.be/nKguVsQi_0I)

It happens when I try to "download the JSF 2.2 mojarra implementation"

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong & a solution so I can complete this tutorial please?

I saw on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293477/eclipse-transfer-failed-zip-file-is-empty) they said to download the 2 jar files but & wanted to use the IDE to do it smoothly rather that me manually downloading it. Why am I getting this error empty zip file error & how do I not get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [eclipse transfer failed zip file is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44293477/eclipse-transfer-failed-zip-file-is-empty)

Comment: Ther reason is IN the page you refer to.